# Where are the CSS and Javascript files located, which Shiny generates during rendering?

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard, shinyjs

Since Shiny Apps is a Web App service, it must generate HTML, CSS and Javascript files during output, correct?

I have written my entire Shiny Code in ui.R, server.R, global.R and with some of the modules. Now I want to integrate this app in my existing website with the same look, feel, and features, but I don't want to have to implement iFrame and other stuff. Also, the server which I am using is not at all set up with R (the one which has a website). Both my website and Shiny App are running on two different servers.

Comment: I suspect the variables are stored in memory since Rshiny runs on top of node. The rest are rendered on the client side

Comment: Does it mean, R shiny creates HTML, CSS files dynamically on the client side when R code gets executed on the server side?

Comment: I think it is yes, it just has the code to generate those tags in-flight